# Dealing with specific user patterns

Tags: discussion

So I've noticed one user who often comes, asks questions, and disappears. I believe many of those questions are not actual problems the user is facing but just for the sake of asking, and many of them are duplicates or generic.

Sure, it can be useful to document useful information for the next guy, but to be honest I'd rather answer questions which actually help someone than to inflate our SE statistics. If the question is asked only to inflate stats or add info - then do us all a favour and also try to answer it yourself instead of having others do all the work while you spam questions.

What's annoying is that some questions have good answers and have been left [unmarked as answered](https://monero.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A1078+is%3Aq+hasaccepted%3Ano+answers%3A1). That's 41 questions with 1+ answers, all asked by the same user! Come on...

I need a reality check here. Am I the only one seeing this?

Comment: I am hoping the user in question comes here to respond. I am confused by the relative small number of accepted answers here compared to questions posted by the same user on other SE network sites.

Comment: sorry to be a ruckus on the forum. i ask alot of the questions because I'm still learning the system and I want to also document them vs asking on reddit or a regular forum. I'll mark my questions answered now. Alot of times on SO people might run into similar questions but asked in a different way so I don't think its a good idea to close it but at most mark it as duplicate. Sorry for the troubles and thanks for answering my questinos @jollymort

Comment: Hey, thanks for stopping by! See my answer below. And don't worry, this is an open community and we can work together to making the site a better and more useful place!

Answer (score 3):

Sure, users should be encouraged to ask questions! We like well-formed questions. But there was a pattern forming so I had to react - especially for forgetting to mark the questions as accepted. I understand that newbies or one-time users sometimes don't do always do that, and maybe even never return to the site, but when an experienced user has so many questions "abandoned" it could signal trouble.

And I agree that many of the questions, even if duplicate, contributed to making certain things already answered before easier to find. That kind of housekeeping I like. But then please find relevant existing answers and answer the question yourself to make it easier to the rest of us.

Other questions prompted people to write informative answers, which is the goal here - good questions and good answers. Thing is, this site is entirely operated by volunteers. So, I'm hoping regulars here also give something back other than only asking questions. It's the asymmetry of questions & answers which bothered me. I mean, after so many questions one would expect an user to have learned something and start to share the obtained knowledge and help around the site as well. Since there was no indication of that, motivation to answer that user's question starts to go down, and at the end could become a housekeeping chore.

If you learned, then please share it back! And try to give **quality answers** to other questions, even your own. Quality is really important in making the site a success. Also, it would take the workload off the rest of us. Effort & research is appreciated! Asking vague questions which require others to do all the work for you is not.

There should be a guideline somewhere... https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

We can consider being more aggressive in closing similar questions as duplicates.

When we have an existing question with a high quality accepted answer more similar(generic) questions do not bring much added value.